# Turn Toast on / off from shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, toast

Is there a way to globally turn on and off toast notifications with a checkbox in shared preferences?

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
        boolean showToast = myPrefs.getBoolean("showToast",
                true);
```

I was thinking maybe making a class:

```
boolean showToast(){
 //code
}
```

BUT thought, SO might have a global solution?

Should I use a different type of notification system?

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're on the right path. I've solved it similar, with a button at my settings View to toogle the `showToast`. I've made a wrapper around the `Toast.makeText()` for checking this each time without the need of repeating the `if(showToast) { ... }` each time.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider extending Toast to create your custom class which is smart enough to read the user preferences before showing the toast.

Then refactor your code to replace Toast with SmartToast.

`SmartToast.makeText(this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

So implement SmartToast.makeText() to return an instance of SmartToast and override show() as follows:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("showToast", true)) {
        super.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the checkbox value in the shared preferences and then use is as a flag, If(flag) { show toast} for example, isn't this the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can only disable or enable toast notifications for your appplication like the way u r doing it...but not globally for all applications

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a enum with one element -

```
public enum YourSingleton {
INSTANCE;    // element in this enum

public static void makeToast(Context context, String msg) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

}
And then to call -

```
 YourSingleton .makeToast(this, "Toast Message");
```

When you want to turn on or off - you can simply do that in the **makeToast()** method.

Answer (score 0):

use onSharedPreferenceChangeListener.